# Minimize the $l_1$ norm

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces

The task is to minimize $|x1 - b|_{l1}$ in $l_1$ norm. Here $1 \in R^{n}$ is a vector of ones, $x \in R$ is a scalar, $b \in R^{n}$.

First of all, I wrote it in a general form without specifying the norm: minimize $|x1-b|$.

Then by the introduction of the equality constraint, it can be written in an equivalent form as:  $$\text{minimize }|y|$$
$$\text{subject to: } y=x1-b $$.

The dual of the problem is $L(\lambda) = |y|+\lambda^T(y-x1+b)$. Taking the infimum we get $g(\lambda) = \inf_{x,y} L(\lambda) = \inf_{x,y}|y|+\lambda^T(y-x1+b) = \inf_{x}\lambda^T(b-x1) \text{ subject to }|\lambda|_{*} \le 1$.

So, the dual problem is $$\text{maximize }\inf_{x}\lambda^T(b-x1)$$
$$\text{subject to: } |\lambda|_{*} \le 1 $$.

Where $|.|_{*}$ is the dual norm.

Is this right so far? What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The little issue with $y$ in the Lagrangian aside, the steps so far are correct. The next step is to focus on $\inf_x \lambda^T(x1) = \inf_x \lambda^T1 x$. When is the infimum finite?

Update based on the discussion:
$$\inf_x \lambda^T1 x = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } \lambda^T1 = 0 \\ -\infty & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I don't know if I am doing this right... If $x < 0$ we can take $\lambda_i \to \infty$ and $\lambda_j = 0, i \not= j$. Then we will get $\inf_{x}\lambda^T1x \to -\infty$. If $x > 0$ similar logic can show that $\inf_{x}\lambda^T1x \to \infty$. So, I guess the only way is that $x = 0$. If I am right the dual problem becomes maximize $\lambda^Tb$ subject to $|\lambda|_{*} \le 1$. I know that the answer to the problem is the median of coefficients of $b$. However, even provided that I am right, I still struggle to see how to get it.

Comment: @user13 you cannot take $\lambda_i \to \infty$, because you are only allowed to optimize over $x$ for $\inf_x$, and $\lambda$ is fixed

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess then the conclusion will remain the same $\inf \lambda^t1x = 0$ at $x = 0$, otherwise, we can take $x \to -\infty$ to get $\inf_x \lambda^T1x \to -\infty$.

Comment: @user13 why would you take $x=0$ if you can let $x\to -\infty$? It is $\inf_x$ after all. Does that mean $\inf_x \lambda^T 1x = -\infty$ always?

Comment: Unless $\lambda^T1 = 0$.

Comment: right, so what is the dual?

Comment: So, the dual problem will be: maximize $\lambda^Tb$ subject to $|\lambda|_{*} \le 1, \lambda^T1 = 0$